# What does these two commands

Tags: sed

I have a  script that I do not quite understand yet.
The script assigns a configuration file to a hardware.

I do not quite understand the following two lines:

`export TYPE=$(dmidecode -s system-product-name | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//')`

`CONFIG_FILE=$(find . -type f -name *.cfg -exec grep -l -i "$TYPE" '{}' \; | sed 's|./||')`

Both assign the result of a query to a variable. The first picks up the product name and replaces characters (which one?).
The second looks for a configuration file using the result from the first query. But what exactly is the search string and what is being replaced here using sed.

Some more info:
There are already some configurations files. If the dmidecode command finds a "HP EliteBook 850 G5" the next step says it would use the "WIN10_HP_ELITE_8x_G5.cfg" file. Now i have to make a file for a "HP ProBook x360 440 G1" and want to understate how this works.

Comment: Have you added some extra spaces in the shown examples? E.g. in the sed expression?

Comment: Sorry, there where som additional spaces in the commands.
I added some more infos.

Comment: The `CONFIG_FILE=...` command will put in the `CONFIG_FILE` variable the list of names of files which _contain_ the string held by the `TYPE` variable and are located in the current directory (`.`) _and its subdirectories_. File names are only required to end in `.cfg`—except, the command _as is_ will fail with an error if the current directory has more than one file whose name ends in `.cfg` unless an option that prevents the shell from globbing was set (e.g. `set -f` in Bash). It should probably be `'*.cfg'` (with quotes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*//'
```

The anchor `^` tells `sed` to start at the beginning of the line and the regex group `[ \t]*` to match all `*` spaces `[ ]` or tabs `[\t]` from the start of the line until the first non-match and replace them with nothing `//` (i.e. to delete them).

Within the square brackets `[]` you may specify a range of characters to match.

```
sed 's/[ \t]*$//'
```

The anchor `$` marks the end of a line, so this time sed matches all spaces and tabs back from the end of the line to the first non-match and, again replaces them with nothing.

Your second expression searches for **all** `.cfg' files below the current directory

```
find . -type f -name *.cfg
```

and `grep` them individually

```
-exec grep -li "$TYPE" '{}' \;
```

looking for a cased insensitive match `-i` for whatever string is stored in the `$TYPE` variable and returns the filename `-l` for any matches. It is impossible to tell from your post what `$TYPE` contains

The final `sed` uses a different separator (`sed` takes the first non-command character in your argument as a separator, so you can use anything that suits you and in this case you don't want the usual `/` because it is one of your search characters and `sed 's/.\///'` is less clear)

```
sed 's|./||'
```

will remove the first two characters from each of the `grep` filenames whenever the second character is a `/`. This is because the first `.` is a wildcard match for 'any character'.

This is probably meant to remove the `./` from all of the pathnames (and it will in this case) but the `.` is interpreted as 'any character' rather than a literal `.`. To ensure **only** a literal `.` is replaced then the special character `.` should be escaped

```
sed 's|\./||'
```

And the `grep` matches are finally bundled as a space separated list into

```
CONFIG_FILE=$(.....)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explaination.
I will test something and then i can say if i get it or not.

Comment: Minor points: 1) It may be worth pointing out that `sed 's/^[ \t]//'` will only match `<tab>`s if it supports an extension to POSIX (as GNU `sed` does); POSIX mandates ``\`` to have no special meaning in bracket expressions. 2) `<newline>`s in the list populating `CONFIG_FILE` will be preserved, thus it won't be exactly "space separated". (Sorry for re-posting, I didn't notice my previous comment wasn't properly formatted).

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/^[\t]*//; s/[\t]*$//'
```

This will replace all tabs before and after line breaks with nothing.

The second `sed` operation has at time of this writing a syntax error and won't work at all.

Comment: Remove the square brackets from around the `\t` as that introduces a subtle shift in it's interpretation. Rather it takes it to mean to remove leading 
and trailing  instances of backslash or alphabet t. Not what it appears at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

- https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode
- regarding the `sed` part of the first line : there are many extra spaces (added when  posting code here ?). Anyway, what this part does is remove `TAB` characters found at the beginning or at the end of lines output by `dmidecode`. The result ends in the `TYPE` variable
- the second line (extra spaces again) is pretty mysterious as we don't have enough information :

  - no information about the `$HW_TYPE` variable
  - the `sed` part looks incomplete to me (are you sure this 2nd line actually works ?)

Comment: It does not remove all tabs, only those preceeding or following a line break.

Comment: @Panki : correct. Just edited my answer. Thx